# how to make a webpage instantly enter full screen

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I am trying to figure out how to make a webpage instantly enter full screen the second it is opened.
I've got this:

```js
var elem = document.documentElement;
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```css
:-webkit-full-screen {
  background-color: white;
}

:-ms-fullscreen {
  background-color: white;
}

:fullscreen {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<button>Random button</button>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And I want openFullscreen() to be called the second the page is opened. Any way to do that?

Comment: No, because that would be incredibly annoying. So the browser vendors blocked that behavior. User input is mandatory.

Comment: *wah wah trumpet noises*

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you never called the functions. See my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
/* Safari syntax */
:-webkit-full-screen {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* IE11 */
:-ms-fullscreen {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Standard syntax */
:fullscreen {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Style the button */
button {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Fullscreen with JavaScript</h2>
<p>Click on the "Open Fullscreen" button to open this page in fullscreen mode. Close it by either clicking the "Esc" key on your keyboard, or with the "Close Fullscreen" button.</p>

<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Fullscreen</button>
<button onclick="closeFullscreen();">Close Fullscreen</button>

<script>
var elem = document.documentElement;
function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function closeFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>

<p>Note: Internet Explorer 10 and earlier versions do not support the msRequestFullscreen() method.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: [https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp#:~:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Fullscreen%20Document,-To%20open%20the](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen.asp#:%7E:text=Try%20it%20Yourself%20%C2%BB-,Fullscreen%20Document,-To%20open%20the)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Events such as mousemove that can be annoying when allowed are not running. You can try this code.

```js
        document.querySelector('html').addEventListener('click', openFullscreen)
        var elem = document.querySelector('.ex');
        function openFullscreen() {
            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
                elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
                elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
                elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
```

```css
   :-webkit-full-screen {
            background-color: white;
        }

        :-ms-fullscreen {
            background-color: white;
        }

        :fullscreen {
            background-color: white;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="ex">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia repellat culpa ipsam tenetur
        inventore quaerat cupiditate quo, voluptate tempora eligendi ratione animi consequatur earum eaque facilis quis
        optio mollitia saepe?</div>
```